# C++: Returning by value with a reference

Tags: c++

I am seeking clarification of what exactly happens when one returns a reference to an object in a function with a return type of that object.

Consider the following function:

```
CObject getObject() {
    CObject localObject;
    CObject &objectRef(localObject);
    return objectRef;
}
```

It is my understanding that this function will return a copy of "localObject", as opposed to returning the reference to "localObject". Is this correct? Is it essentially creating and returning a new object with localObject as the constructor parameter? 
E.g.,

```
CObject newObject(localObject);
```

Comment: Your doing it on the stack....do on heap insted

Comment: do in heap if you need heap not just to make this example work

Answer (score 6):

It will return a **copy** of your object. However, be careful if you change your function declaration to return a reference, your code will result in Undefined Behavior.

**Example:**

```
class CObject{
    public:
    CObject(){std::cout << "cosntructing ";}
    CObject(const CObject& other){std::cout << "copying ";}
};

CObject getObject(){
    CObject localObject;
    CObject &objectRef(localObject);
    return objectRef;
}

int main(){
   auto result =  getObject();
}
```

This will result in:

> cosntructing
>   copying

**Note**: you may not get the same results if your compiler is fully optimizing the code due to RVO. So turn off all optimization and try.
As @Caduchon stated that even with no optimization, results can change due to copy-elision.

---

Example of the function with **undefined behavior**:

```
CObject& getObject() {
    CObject localObject;
    CObject &objectRef(localObject);
    return objectRef;
}
```

Comment: Note that the copy can be omitted if the result is assigned to a new variable. The compiler can see it and construct directly the variable out of the function.

Comment: @Caduchon you were faster than me :) it was edited. Thanks for mentioning

Comment: I see. So as long as the return type is by value, it will always construct a copy of the object that is being given through the reference. Thanks for the thorough answer!

Comment: It's not due to the optimization. It's possible even with `-O0`(I juste tried).

Comment: I use gcc 4.8.3. See this example ( http://pasted.co/5fe64d0f ) compiled with `g++ copy.cpp -o copy -O0`

Comment: I've set up similar code, giving CObject two members: an int and a string.    My getObject() returns a CObject&.  In main(), assigning `auto result = newObject` simply does not compile ('result' was not declared in this scope).  Using `CObject result = getObject()` results in a copy of the int, but not the string.  You'll get some fun output with `CObject& result = getObject()`.  This is using gcc 5.3.1 via `g++ test.out`

Comment: @buratino do you have c++11?

Comment: @HumamHelfawi Hah!  That slipped my mind.  I'll edit that comment to reflect c++11.

Nevermind, I can't edit it.  Using `g++ -std=c++11 test.out` properly compiles the version of the code using `auto result = getObject()` (which I also typo'd in my previous comment as `auto result = newObject`), and it yields the same result as `CObject result = getObject()`; the int is copied but the string is not.

Comment: May you post a question with full code and details? it will help to identify the problem better. and other people could help better in that too.

Comment: It was not meant to be a question, it was just an observation.  Still, the code can be found [here](http://pasted.co/e523d68a).  After that code is run, I just modified `CObject newObject = getObject();` to be `CObject& newObject = getObject();`.  The purpose of this was to observe some of the undefined behavior of getObject() returning CObject&.

Comment: @buratino your code has an undefined behavior. Anything may happen including bombing the PC that run it. You can not treat UB in a logical way

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that it is not returning a reference to the local object. In terms of what actually is returned, the answer is a little bit more subtle. Due to something called [return value optimisation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision), the compiler will actually only create one instance of `CObject` as a result of calling the function. It is an optimisation trick that basically means the original `localObject` is constructed in such a way as to be directly usable by the calling function - so no copy construction is necessary upon the return of the call.